# INSERT ... SELECT, InnoDB and locking

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I came accross the following behaviour with InnoDB engine under MySQL 5.5.34 (on Ubuntu 12.04).

When performing `INSERT ... SELECT` statements, some unexpected rows seem to be locked in the table being read from.

Let me give an example. Suppose two tables `table_source` and `table_dest` with the following structure (particular attention to the indices):

```
CREATE TABLE table_source (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  group_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  data text NOT NULL,
  created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY group_id_created (group_id,created)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE table_dest (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  group_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  data text NOT NULL,
  created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY group_id_created (group_id,created)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Suppose I now execute the following transaction:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table_dest 
    SELECT * FROM table_source WHERE group_id = 3 AND created < '2014-01-04';
....
```

Then the source table seems to be locked for `INSERT` with `group_id` 2:

```
INSERT INTO table_source (group_id, data, created) 
    VALUES (2, 'data', NOW()); --< This locks
```

Here are some other statements and if they lock or not:

```
INSERT INTO table_source (group_id, data, created) 
    VALUES (3, 'data', NOW()); --< Does not lock

INSERT INTO table_source (group_id, data, created) 
    VALUES (1, 'data', NOW()); --< Does not lock

INSERT INTO table_source (group_id, data, created) 
    VALUES (3, 'data', '2014-01-01'); --< Does lock
```

Can somebody explain me why this happens (I suppose it has something to do with gap locks)? Is there a way to avoid this (I still want to keep the `REPEATABLE READ` isolation level)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct. The rows in the table being read from are locked with a shared lock (the `SELECT` is implicitly `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`). There isn't a way to avoid this. It's sort of what you're asking the system for: copy all rows which match a condition. The only way to ensure that is in fact all rows that match the condition and that that list does not change during or immediately after the execution of that statement, is to lock the rows.

As a clarification regarding why you are unable to `INSERT` with `group_id = 2`:

This has to do with your query being specifically `WHERE group_id = 3 AND created < '2014-01-04'` on `KEY group_id_created (group_id, created)`. In order to search all rows which match `group_id = 3 AND created < '2014-01-04'` the index will be traversed backwards starting with the first row which exceeds  that condition the upper bound, which is `(3, '2014-01-14')` and continuing until finding a row which does not match the condition, which since `created` has no lower bound will be the first row where `group_id < 3` which of course is `group_id = 2`.

That means that the first row encountered with `group_id = 2` is **also** locked, which will be the row with the maximum `created` value. This will make it impossible to `INSERT` into the "gap" between `(2, MAX(created))` and `(3, MIN(created))` (not proper SQL of course, just pseudo-SQL), although this is not a "gap lock" specifically.

Comment: Thanks I get that the SELECT statement gets implicitely converted to a SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE. However what I still don't quite get is why trying to insert a row with group_id = 2 locks (shouldn't the share lock only be on rows with group_id = 3?)

Comment: Sorry, I missed some of the intent of your question. I added some clarifications just now.

Comment: Thanks for this explaination, this is much clearer now.